# What tables were accessed last

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to know the top N tables that were accessed. I only got for databases and most of the links in google address last date access for a particular table.

```
SELECT DatabaseName, MAX(LastAccessDate) LastAccessDate
FROM
    (SELECT
        DB_NAME(database_id) DatabaseName
        , last_user_seek
        , last_user_scan
        , last_user_lookup
        , last_user_update
    FROM sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats) AS PivotTable
UNPIVOT 
    (LastAccessDate FOR last_user_access IN
        (last_user_seek
        , last_user_scan
        , last_user_lookup
        , last_user_update)
    ) AS UnpivotTable
GROUP BY DatabaseName
HAVING DatabaseName NOT IN ('master', 'tempdb', 'model', 'msdb')
ORDER BY 2
```

Now I need this for tables. Any idea or link, please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this easily one database at a time, with a slight adjustment to your code:

```
USE Your_Database;
GO

SELECT [schema]  = OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME([object_id]), 
  [object]       = OBJECT_NAME([object_id]), 
  LastAccessDate = MAX(LastAccessDate)
FROM
    (SELECT
        [object_id]
        , last_user_seek
        , last_user_scan
        , last_user_lookup
        , last_user_update
    FROM sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats
    WHERE database_id = DB_ID()) AS PivotTable
UNPIVOT 
    (LastAccessDate FOR last_user_access IN
        (last_user_seek
        , last_user_scan
        , last_user_lookup
        , last_user_update)
    ) AS UnpivotTable
GROUP BY [object_id]
ORDER BY LastAccessDate;
```

Of course this is only good since the last service restart or reconfigure.

- [When was my database / table last accessed?](https://sqlblog.org/2008/05/06/when-was-my-database-table-last-accessed)

If you want to do this per database, you can use my custom `sp_MSforeachdb` replacements:

- [Making a more reliable and flexible sp_MSforeachdb](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2201/making-a-more-reliable-and-flexible-spmsforeachdb/?utm_source=AaronBertrand)
- [Execute a Command in the Context of Each Database in SQL Server using sp_ineachdb](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5686/execute-a-command-in-the-context-of-each-database-in-sql-server-using-spineachdb/?utm_source=AaronBertrand)
- [Execute a Command in the Context of Each Database in SQL Server - Part 2](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5694/execute-a-command-in-the-context-of-each-database-in-sql-server--part-2/?utm_source=AaronBertrand)

Comment: I just found that post on your blog and was going to post it here. :) https://sqlblog.org/2008/05/06/when-was-my-database-table-last-accessed